# Select the correct span and div in jquery using classes

Tags: jquery, selector

I am trying to create a navigation that will collapse on click. It is working, but I want to only select the set clicked.

```
<div class="sidenav-set">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleSet()" class="sidenav-set-link">Apply<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
    <div class="sidenav-links">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidenav-set">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleSet()" class="sidenav-set-link">Information <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
    <div class="sidenav-links">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
```

The jquery I have is this:

```
function toggleSet() {
  $(".sidenav-set-link span").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up")
  $(".sidenav-links").toggle('slow')
}
```

This works, but it operates on all the sets. I want to click the link a the top of a set, change out the class on the up/down arrow and show/hide the set of .sidenav-links

I've tried several things that have not worked, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are using inline JS, rather than adding an eventlistener, you could parse `e` as a parameter. `e` will now be your clicked element. It's similar to using `this` when working with eventlisteners, rather than inline JS. Then you can use stuff like `e.find()`, `e.parent()`, `e.closest()` etc., whichever you need, to toggle the proper pane.

Comment: You should also look to replicate your functionality with a runable code-snippet. It would yield the best answers for you as well, since people will have something concrete to test against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `$(this)` and a selector to find the elements you want to modify.

```js
function toggleSet() {
  $(this).find("span").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
  $(this).parents(".sidenav-set").find(".sidenav-links").toggle('slow');
}
```

Comment: Chose this as the answer, as I can make it work stand alone, but this does not work within my Drupal 8 installation. Thanks for the help!